# I can't make field changes in table after syncdb .

Tags: sql, django

I can't make field changes in table  after syncdb . I tried drop the table and syncdb recreate it. I am also using south to manage database migrationss. All syncdb will do is create tables that do not already exist. What should i do to change  schema and add fields, after syncdb created tables.

Comment: Have you looked at django tutorials/docs on doing that? What's different with your config?

Comment: You should [read the docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html). If you have, please post which commands you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply your changes with

```
./manage.py migrate yourapp
```

after you have generated a migration with

```
./manage.py schemamigration yourapp --auto
```

A quick start guide how to use South: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Answer (score -3):

Edit the model in models.py so that it has the new structure you want, then delete the table and let syncdb recreate it for you.

Comment: There's no reason to do such a thing if you've south installed.